# Why I could connect API via axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I created react app with Typescript and I made a request via axios.

Here is my original code.

```
// /src/axios.js

import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://api.baseurl.org",
});

export default instance;
```

```
// /src/component.js

import React from "react";
import axios from "./axios";

...

const Component = ({ fetchUrl }) => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
    }
    ...
};

...
```

I could get responses correctly, but don't know why I could make a request.

In axios.js file, I export `instance`, not `axios`.
In component.js file, I import `axios`.

I think I should import `instance` in component.js, that is, modify the file like this :

```
// /src/component.js modified

import React from "react";
import instance from "./axios";

...

const Component = ({ fetchUrl }) => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const request = await instance.get(fetchUrl);
    }
    ...
};

...
```

I could get the same result correctly.
Two ways of using axios instance made correct results.

**Why I could connect API with the original code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In axios.js file, I export instance, not axios. In component.js file, I import axios.

You're using a **default** export, not a named export. The name you assign to it is completely up to the module doing the importing.

---

Consider:

```
const foo = 123;
export default foo;
export const bar = 456;
```

To import that you say:

```
import whatever_you_want_to_call_it, { bar as anything_you_like } from './export.mjs';
```

`bar` is a named export so you have to specify that it is `bar` you want to import (but giving it a different name is optional). The default export has to be given a name, but which name is entirely up to you.